# Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int welcomeSocket, newSocket;
  char buffer[1024];
  char str[1024];
  int len,k,i;
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  welcomeSocket= socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

  serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port=htons(17100);
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero,'\0',sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

  bind (welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));


  if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0)
        printf("Listening!\n");


  else
        printf("Error\n");


  addr_size= sizeof serverStorage;
  newSocket=accept(welcomeSocket,(struct 
  sockaddr*)&serverStorage,&addr_size);
  strcpy(buffer,"Enter string you want reversed or type exit: \n");
  send(newSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);




  do
  {
        memset(buffer,0,strlen(buffer));
        recv(newSocket,buffer,1024,0);
        if(strcmp(buffer,"exit")==0)
                break;
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        len=strlen(buffer);
        k=len-1;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
                str[i]=buffer[k];            
                k--;
        }


        send(newSocket,str,strlen(str),0);
  }while(strcmp(buffer,"exit")!=0);


  return 0;
}
```

While compiling this code i get the following error: 
    gcc jason.c 
    Undefined                       first referenced
    symbol                             in file
    bind                                /tmp/cc9aqprX.o
    recv                                /tmp/cc9aqprX.o
    send                                /tmp/cc9aqprX.o
    accept                              /tmp/cc9aqprX.o
    listen                              /tmp/cc9aqprX.o
    socket                              /tmp/cc9aqprX.o
    inet_addr                           /tmp/cc9aqprX.o
    ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please help resolving this issue?

Comment: How do you build? Please provide the commandline.

Comment: apologies, for compiling :gcc jason.c , is used

Comment: And would you need to use a library with those network headers you are using?

Comment: no, the c compiler should have it by default!

Comment: Adding "#include <arpa/inet.h>" made it compile on my system

Comment: what system did you use ole?